# OS X - Too many files in a folder, can't move them

Tags: macos

I have over 200,000 files in a folder, which I need to sequence into a movie. Quicktime Pro gives me an error so I'm trying to split up the images into various folders. Sadly, Finder is not letting me copy files to a new folder. If I go one by one, then it kind of works but each one will take a few minutes.

I'm on 10.6.8.

Any hints would be hugely appreciated for moving these files out of the folder.

Comment: Where are those files? Aren't they on NTFS partition?

Comment: No, they are on a Mac OS Extended (Journaled) partition. It's in my documents folder. Thanks for taking the time...

Comment: It's realy strange, that you can't move them. What error do you get when you try to move/copy them?

Comment: Are these files named according to a pattern? If so, slhck here has brought you half-way home. (You can make a regex/glob-pattern based on the pattern and use that in the `find` command, or someone here might show you how.)

Comment: @Kamil, I don't get any errors, it just stalls and does nothing.

Comment: @jpaugh, yeah they are named incrementally. I will attempt slhck's approach. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is, with my find, I can do something like `find /folder -regex 'sameprefix[0-9]{1,3}.jpg'`, which would match the first 1000 files. I don't if Mac's find util is as useful though.

Comment: @jpaugh OS X' `find` also supports the `regex` option.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily move them via Terminal. First of all, list the files. This could take a while, and you can abort it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

> `find /your-folder -maxdepth 1 -type f`

We use `maxdepth 1` to restrict results to your current directory only, not recursively going to subdirectories.

Once you're sure the output is correct, you can move them. `find` will do this one by one for you. Replace the folder names as needed. For example, the Movies directory in your home directory would be `~/Movies`.

The following will move **all** files in `your-folder` somewhere else.

> `find /your-folder -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv '{}' /other-folder \;`

Of course, you probably don't want to move all files, so you can restrict the results to certain names:

> `find /your-folder -iname "*.jpg" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv '{}' /other-folder \;`

Here, you could change `*.jpg` as you like. The asterisk `*` matches any character, and you can play with that to match only a subset of the files you want to move. You can even use a regular expression here, as [@jpaugh](https://superuser.com/users/86708/jpaugh) notes:

> `find /your-folder -regex 'prefix[0-9]{1,3}.jpg' …`

This would match the first 1000 files if they're correctly named from `prefix0.jpg` to `prefix999.jpg`.

Comment: Too bad that OS X's `mv` doesn't support the `-t` target argument. Otherwise `find -print0` and `xargs -0` would have been a time saving alternative.

Comment: If people broke down the terminal this way more often, the world would be a better place. Nice! :-)